# SoftKeyboard : Switch Keyboard

Tags: android, keyboard

So my problem is as follows:

I am working on the "Unmodified SoftKeyboard Demo Project" , I created another keyboard (Azerty) with Copy/Paste as the Qwerty. When I call `mInputView.setKeyboard(mAzertyKeyboard);` by pressing a button , the keyboard is switched, but the layout is big and badly displayed, I mean I can't see all keys just the half of the keyboard on the screen. Does switching a keyboard require another call like `Draw`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the number of key in a row is the same as the qwerty keyboard.
Anyway, you should show us the layout here if you want some help

Comment: Thanks you for your Answer , but i Discontinued the SoftKeyboard Project Beacause of too many Bug and the Project Itself is outdated